# Bash, cut word with dot character from string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a string:

> Log for: squid.log.2017.11.13

I need to cut out `squid.log.` so that I see:

> Log for: 2017.11.13

I tried to `cut`

```
echo "Log for: squid.log.2017.11.13" | cut -d'.' -f3-5
```

But I ended up with:

> 2017.11.13

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Is it always literally "squid.log.", or could it be any text before the year.month.day?

Comment: always `squid.log`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to cut the unwanted part:

```
echo "Log for: squid.log.2017.11.13" | sed 's/squid\.log\.//'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed` to *remove* the part you *don't* want:

```
echo "Log for: squid.log.2017.11.13" | sed 's/squid\.log\.//'
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue! a non-standard approach to break the monotony...

define the to be removed text as field separator and parse and print the input line.

```
$ echo Log for: squid.log.2017.11.13 | awk -F' squid\\.log\\.' '{$1=$1}1'

Log for: 2017.11.13
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit more reusable than the previous ones offered:

```
awk '/^Log/{ split($3,x,"."); print $1" "$2" "x[length(x)-2]"."x[length(x)-1]"."x[length(x)] };'
```

This looks for all lines starting with `Log`, then grabs the 3rd column which contains `squid.log.2017.11.13` and utilizes the the `split` built-in to break up the string in to array `x` using the `.` as the delimiter. Once we have our array `x`, we know that the last 3 values will always be the date, and this will work regardless of the rest of the string, (even if `squid.log` was something different) - we can use the `length` built-in to make sure we only get the last three elements.

Then we just print our reformatted string `print $1" "$2" "x[length(x)-2]"."x[length(x)-1]"."x[length(x)]` - reinserting the `.`'s in the appropriate places since they were stripped by using them as the `split` delimiter.

Output:
`Log for: 2017.11.13`